# Get entrypoint operation (get_entrypoint_opt) fails

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, ligo

I have some troubles to call a contract.

This is the scenario:

Contract B (Entrypoint method "transfer"):

```
(pair %transfer (bytes %args1)
                              (pair (string %args2)
                                      (pair (string %args3)
                                             (pair (address %args4)
                                                    (pair (address %args5)
                                                           (nat %args6))))))
```

Contract A (which will call Contract B entrypoint method "transfer"):

```
type transfer is Transfer of (bytes * (string * (string * (address * (address * nat)))))

const contract : contract(transfer) = 
            case (Tezos.get_entrypoint_opt("%transfer", contractAddress): option(contract(transfer))) of 
            | Some (c) -> c
            | None -> (failwith("not a correct contract") : contract(transfer))
            end;
```

I am quite sure, something inside this statement is wrong for some reason

```
"type transfer is Transfer of (bytes * (string * (string * (address * (address * nat)))))"
```

But everytime failwith("not a correct contract") will be triggered

PS: I tried to call another method on contract B with only three parameters:

```
type approve is Approve of (bytes * (string * string))
```

Everything works fine with three parameters. But if I need to call a method with some more parameters, it fails.

Can somebody help ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you test it? On-chain directly or with the Ligo IDE/command line?

Comment: Contract A entrypoint (which includes the get_entrypoint_opt call) is called with taquito.
The transaction failed with the message "not a correct contract)
Means that get_entrypoint_opt returns "None"

Comment: So it looks like the contracts are on-chain, would you mind sharing their addresses? I would like to have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! I am using in both contracts michelson_pairs for the type of the entrypoint. I also added some annotations

For example:

```
type transfer is michelson_pair(bytes, "args1", michelson_pair(string, "args2", string, "args3"),"")
```

I just removed the annotations:

```
type transfer is michelson_pair(bytes, "", michelson_pair(string, "", string, ""),"")
```